# innerHTML not working inside closure

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I'm using then `mysql` module to grab some data from a database and trying to write them to an HTML document but the `document.getElementById` statement doesn't seem to work inside the query statement. Here's the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wtv">YOU LOSE, SIR!</div>
        <script>=
            var mysql = require('mysql');

            var con = mysql.createConnection({
                host: "localhost",
                user: "MYUSERNAME",
                password: "MYPASSWORD",
                database: "travel"
            });

            con.connect(function(err) {
                if (err) throw err;
                con.query("SELECT rooms.*, hotels.name AS hotel_name FROM rooms JOIN hotels ON rooms.hotel_id = hotels.id", function (err, result, fields) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    makeHTML(result);
                });
            });


            function makeHTML(list) {
                var outp = "<ul>lolz";
                for (i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                    outp += "<i><ul><p>Room "
                        +list[i].room_num.toString()
                        +" at "+list[i].hotel_name+".</p><i>Price: "
                        +list[i].price.toString()+"<br></i><i>Balconies: "
                        +list[i].balconies.toString()+"</i></ul></i><br><br>";
                };
                outp += "</ul>";
                document.getElementById("wtv").innerHTML = outp;
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The div contents do not update, I'm rather new to javascript so I'm probably missing something rather obvious. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use `document.write`.

Comment: You can't use MySQL from the client

Comment: When you press F12 are there any errors in the console? I think SLaks is correct; you can't use that package in a browser, it's meant to be used in nodejs.